# My CPU temperature is jumping down and up when browsing

Tags: malware, cpu-usage, cpu-temperature

When i'm just browsing the web (not watching a video) my CPU usage and temperature starts bouncing like a ball.
It drops and then rises again.
And now as im writing this my cpu fan is quiet like a cat that is purring.

I keep my PC clean and i take care of it,its not dusty and it aint dirty.
I cleaned my PC with malwarebytes in safe mode and it found nothing,could it be some hidden malware or what??

EDIT:My PC Specs are:
GPU - Radeon R7 260X

CPU - Pentium G3430

8GB RAM

Theese specs can run GTA 5 on high settings but not literally everything set to max at 40FPS,runs everything at medium at 60FPS with VSYNC on.

Comment: What is the issue? If your system  is operating normally, and the maximum operating temperature for the CPU is not exceeded, there is no problem. http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Pentium-G3430-vs-Intel-Core-i3-3240 lists 72 C as a safe limit.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to worry at all. My PCs, 2 laptops and 1 desktop, using certain monitor programs, all report this issue at low load. I checked the fan which was not running at all. I suppose it's a bug hidden somewhere in the API or so.